# Dragging mouse across canvas draws on wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a total number of five canvas where centred one is main canvas where I am trying to draw with mouse events and drag img from other four canvas and drop where, for now, I am stuck debugging. When I move a mouse to draw I draw but in wrong place in where a mouse is clicked. Sorry for my bad English.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing;

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
};
el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

}
body {
 font-size: 120%;
 background: #F8F8FF;
}

form, .content {
 width: 30%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
canvas {
 
 padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

#myCanvas1 {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: left;
}

#myCanvas2 {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: right;
}

#myCanvas3 {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: initial;
}

#myCanvas4 {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas3" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas4" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: How would we know what it is that you're doing wrong without any code and without any explanation as to what that 'wrong way' is?

Comment: I am really sorry for not uploading codes because StackOverflow is new to me, it was recommended by my professor.

Comment: No problem - you've posted it now so I'll upvote and retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw your segments relative to the mouse offset from the element you want to draw on, in this case your primary `<canvas>`.

This is how you get the offset:

Instead of:

```
ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY)
```

use:

```
ctx.moveTo(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop)
```

and instead of:

```
ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY)
```

use:

```
ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop)
```

Here's the full example:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
var isDrawing;

el.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  ctx.moveTo(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 120%;
  background: #F8F8FF;
}

form, .content {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B0C4DE;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

canvas {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

#myCanvas1 {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
}

#myCanvas2 {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: right;
}

#myCanvas3 {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: initial;
}

#myCanvas4 {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas3" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas4" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: :D :D I did it.